# PyQt Clear the menubar

Tags: python, pyqt, qmenu, qmenubar

Is there a quick way to clear the menu bar i.e. Remove all menus in PyQt.

The reason I ask is that I am developing a modular application. Each module provides it's own menus and gives a weighting to where that menu should appear. Each module can also add a menuAction to another modules menu, however when that happens it changes the order of the menus. What i want to do is when the menus have finished being created is to remove them all and then re add them.

I know this will work because I can re add them now and they appear in the correct order but all the previous menus are still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try `QMenu.clear (self)`

```
mymenu = QtGui.QMenu("Menu")

mymenu.clear()
```